# Java compile-error Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, generics, lambda, compiler-errors

My code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ok
    get1(Student::getName);
    // error! why?
    get2(Student::getName);
}


public static <T, R> void get1(Function<T, R> fun) {
    // ok! why?
    get2(fun);
}

public static void get2(Function<?, ?> fun) {

}

@Data
class Student {
    private String name;
}
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBVe6.png)

Why get2 compile error and report 'Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context', but get1 is ok?

This problem may be caused by generics.

Hope someone can answer my confusion.

Comment: The question's underlying is already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context

Comment: I just compiled your program.   I don't get that error message.  Not certain what @Data is doing but your class is missing a getter.  When I add the getter What I get is `The type Snippet2.Student does not define getName(Object) that is applicable here. The method get2(Function<?,?>) in the type Snippet2 is not applicable for the arguments (Student::getName)`

Comment: @WJS That annotation adds the getter.

Comment: @StephenQu copy/pasting the exact code you wrote and compiling it: No errors. Hence, VTC: Not reproducible. Perhaps double check that you're compiling what you think you are compiling / that you have saved this file in your editor.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Interesting you didn't get any compilation errors.  Something is awry.  I am using Eclipse.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I add error image above.  I am using idea

Comment: @WJS `@Data` is `lombok.Data`. `Function` is `java.util.function.Function`.

Comment: What in the world.  How on earth is this a duplicate of a question about using non-static members in static methods?  Method references can be used anywhere.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one.  It helps to recall that this:

```
Function<?, ?> fun
```

is exactly the same as writing this:

```
Function<? extends Object, ? extends Object> fun
```

When the compiler attempts to resolve a call to get2, such as `get2(Student::getName)`, it evaluates the generic parameters one by one.  First, it sees that the first parameter is `? extends Object`.  The compiler only knows that the first argument will be… Object or some subclass of Object.  (You, the human, know that it’s a Student instance, but the compiler doesn’t know that.)

With only that information at its disposal, the compiler is not able to assume that the argument has a getName method.

I found this a little easier to understand by replacing `Student::getName` with a lambda:

```
get2(s -> s.getName());
```

That also produces a compiler error, but the cause is more apparent:  `s` is only known to be Object or some subclass of Object, so how can the compiler assume it has a `getName()` method?

But if I tell the compiler exactly what type `s` is, it will compile:

```
get2((Student s) -> s.getName());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer partially answers my confusion, but I still have some questions. Why get1 is ok? Why get2(fun) is ok？

Comment: @StephenQu If you’re asking why get1 compiles in your code, it’s because that code is not asking the compiler to assume the presence of a getName method.  It will work for any type and any Function.